# how to make an entry into a string, and then into an input so I can put 4 entries into a formula?

Tags: python, tkinter

- I just need to convert an entry into a string so I can then turn the string into an integer or float. Thanks
- I've tried to make strange things with parenthesis but nothing seems to work. I´m sorry I didn´t put the code but I didn't quite know how to pass the code in a fast way here.
- I need to make entry 3, 4, 5 and 6 entries and then whether integers or float

  ```
  root.title("Exemption?")  
  root.geometry("400x200")  
  root["bg"] = "green"  

  def pn(a,b,c,d):  
          return (720-2*d-a-b-2*c)/2  

  label1 = Label(root, text = "Name:")  
  label2 = Label(root, text = "Subject:")  
  label3 = Label(root, text = "Average 1:")  
  label4 = Label(root, text = "Average 2:")  
  label5 = Label(root, text = "Average 3:")  
  label6 = Label(root, text = "Average 4:")  

  entry1 = Entry(root)  
  entry2 = Entry(root)  
  a = entry3 = Entry(root)  
  b = entry4 = Entry(root)  
  c = entry5 = Entry(root)  
  d = entry6 = Entry(root)  

  button = Button(root, text="Average needed", command= pn)  

  label1.grid(row=1,column=1)  
  label2.grid(row=2,column=1)  
  label3.grid(row=3,column=1)  
  label4.grid(row=4,column=1)  
  label5.grid(row=5,column=1)  
  label6.grid(row=6,column=1)  

  entry1.grid(row=1,column=2)  
  entry2.grid(row=2,column=2)  
  entry3.grid(row=3,column=2)  
  entry4.grid(row=4,column=2)  
  entry5.grid(row=5,column=2)  
  entry6.grid(row=6,column=2)  

  button.grid(row=7,column=2)  

  root.mainloop()
  ```

Comment: the question is not clear. What code have you tried so far, what error have you gotten? Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `StringVar()` to create your variable:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("TkApp")

var = StringVar()

def varWriter(*args):
    print var.get()
    print type(var.get())
    print int(var.get())
    print type(int(var.get()))
    print float(var.get())
    print type(float(var.get()))
var.trace("w", varWriter)

label = Label(root, textvariable=var)
label.pack()

text_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=var)
text_entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

But you have to be careful about arbitrarily changing source data type.

[More information](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm).

**EDIT:**

According to OP's request:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title("Exemption?")

root.geometry("400x200")

root["bg"] = "green"

a = StringVar()
b = StringVar()
c = StringVar()
d = StringVar()

int_a = 0
int_b = 0
int_c = 0
int_d = 0

def pn(int_a, int_b, int_c, int_d):
        print (720 - 2 * int_d - int_a - int_b - 2 * int_c ) / 2

def aWriter(*args):
    global int_a
    int_a = int(a.get())

def bWriter(*args):
    global int_b
    int_b = int(b.get())

def cWriter(*args):
    global int_c
    int_c = int(c.get())

def dWriter(*args):
    global int_d
    int_d = int(d.get())

a.trace("w", aWriter)
b.trace("w", bWriter)
c.trace("w", cWriter)
d.trace("w", dWriter)

label1 = Label(root, text = "Name:")

label2 = Label(root, text = "Subject:")

label3 = Label(root, text = "Average 1:", textvariable=a)

label4 = Label(root, text = "Average 2:", textvariable=b)

label5 = Label(root, text = "Average 3:", textvariable=c)

label6 = Label(root, text = "Average 4:", textvariable=d)

entry1 = Entry(root)

entry2 = Entry(root)

entry3 = Entry(root, textvariable=a)

entry4 = Entry(root, textvariable=b)

entry5 = Entry(root, textvariable=c)

entry6 = Entry(root, textvariable=d)

button = Button(root, text="Average needed", command=pn(int_a,int_b,int_c,int_d))

label1.grid(row=1,column=1)

label2.grid(row=2,column=1)

label3.grid(row=3,column=1)

label4.grid(row=4,column=1)

label5.grid(row=5,column=1)

label6.grid(row=6,column=1)

entry1.grid(row=1,column=2)

entry2.grid(row=2,column=2)

entry3.grid(row=3,column=2)

entry4.grid(row=4,column=2)

entry5.grid(row=5,column=2)

entry6.grid(row=6,column=2)

button.grid(row=7,column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I´ve posted the code on the top. I´m making some changes to the code at the moment with your answer, if you could tell me where to insert the StringVar; that would help me a lot.

Comment: Sure, it´s almost ready, found a few things that still don´t work (my button, but that´s something my colliege can fix). The code I sent to him was basically the one you sent me, he´s gonna do the button thing. Thanks a lot by the way. I´ll send you the updated code as soon as my colliege sends it to me again, although that might take some time, since he´s not at his home/contact with his files and stuff.